# Drools Fusion rule language: pedometer rule

Tags: java, drools, complex-event-processing, drools-fusion

I'm a newbie to Drools (version 6.3) and I have some trouble coming up with a specific rule. I have a class called Steps with just a simple field `double steps;`. Each step event represent the steps taken since the previous event and
I have a working rule that says that you need to get moving when you do not do
50 steps in the last hour:

```
declare Steps
    @role(event)
end

rule "STEPS RULE"
when
    $totalSteps : Number( doubleValue < 50 ) from accumulate(
        Steps( stepsCount : steps ) over window:time( 1h ) from entry-point     
    "entrySteps", sum( stepsCount ) )

then
    System.out.println("STEPS RULE: get moving!");
end
```

Now instead that each event is the steps taken since previous event, I want that they represent the cumulative steps. So if an event has 50 steps and you take 20 steps, then I want that the next event has 70 steps. The question is how can I
change my rule so it would still work?

Comment: You need to clarify your terms. If `Steps` is an incoming event, its data is fixed - so if it contains 50 steps, then that's it. You can *derive* something from two events in a sequence, so that one Steps with 50 and the next one with 20 produces a sum of 70, but that doesn't appear to be your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a pedometer you'll need another class, distinct from Steps, your event class. The rules for updating your pedometer are simple.

```
rule "create pedometer"
when
    Steps( $s: steps )
    not Pedometer()
then
    insert( new Pedometer( $s ) );
end

rule "update pedometer"
no-loop
when
    Steps( $s: steps )
    $p: Pedometer( $r: readout )
then
    modify( $p ){
        setReadout( $r + $s )
    }
end
```

**Edit** If Steps already contains accumulated values, it's a little more complicated since you need to calculate the differences between the first and the last pedometer readings in the window.

```
rule "ACC STEPS RULE"
when
    accumulate( Steps( $s : steps )
                over window:time( 1h ) from entry-point "entrySteps"; 
        $fst: min( $s ), $lst: max( $s );
        $lst - $fst < 50 )
then
    System.out.println("STEPS RULE: get moving!");
end
```

There should be at least one reading per hour or another rule detecting this situation.

Comment: I think we misunderstood each other. I want the same rule as before. The new events that I have is simply the cumulative steps. I simply change the field the interpretation of my field "steps" in the class Steps. So now I event1 has for example 50 steps and event2 has 70 steps. Which means 20 steps have been taken since the last event (event1). I want the same rule so if you do less then 50 steps in one hour, the rule fires.
Example: event1:20 steps -> 30 minutes go by -> event2:40 steps -> 35 minutes go by -> event3: 45 steps ->  rule fires.

Comment: It's usually better to describe the actual situation right away, not first elaborate on another one and then zoom in on reality. - I've updated my answer.